# where does python logging module write log by default?

Tags: python, jenkins, logging

I have a python script run by **jenkins**. [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module is used.

```
logging.basicConfig(filename="/tmp/test.log",
                    format="%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s",
                    filemode="a",
                    level=logging.INFO)
```

If the above config removed, I cannot find the log generated by the following statement:

```
logging.info("xxxxxxx")
```

I did not find it in syslog of the jenkins machine. I did not find it in the jenkins console output.

Any hints? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, logging writes to stderr. The reason you're not seeing the statement printed is because the default log level is warning.

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.error('a message!')
ERROR:root:a message!
>>> logging.warning('a message!')
WARNING:root:a message!
>>> logging.info('a message!')
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

The help for the logging module says:

> The default behaviour is to create a StreamHandler which writes to
>           sys.stderr, set a formatter using the BASIC_FORMAT format string, and
>           add the handler to the root logger.

As pointed out in the (now deleted) comment, this description is for `basicConfig()` which indeed is not called immediately. What really happens is that the root logger is initialized in a functionally equivalent way and that's what is used as the default logger. It is actually initialized in two phases: at module load time, the root logger is initialized like this:

```
root = RootLogger(WARNING)
Logger.root = root
Logger.manager = Manager(Logger.root)
```

but no handler is attached:

```
>>> logging.root.__dict__
{'name': 'root', 'parent': None, 'handlers': [], 'level': 30, 'disabled': 0, 'propagate': 1, 'filters': []}
```

When a `logging.warning()` (or `error()` or `info()` or ...) is called, `basicConfig()` is called which adds the StreamHandler to sys.stderr:

```
def warning(msg, *args, **kwargs):
"""
Log a message with severity 'WARNING' on the root logger.
"""
if len(root.handlers) == 0:
    basicConfig()
root.warning(msg, *args, **kwargs)
```

This is python2.7. I assume python3 works the same way but I have not checked.